# Image slider with Bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Is there a way to create and image slide like this http://viavoxproduction.com/ with bootstrap? If so I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap javascript comes with a number of pre-created animations you can use. It might not make what you are looking to do perfectly, but it is at least a place to start.

Specifically, the bootstrap carousel has recently been updated to be much better.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Also, make sure you load your JS libraries, first with jquery (which in example below I pull from google's AJAX library which hosts these online), then boostrap js (min version for speed), then your custom code. For example at the bottom of your html page add:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Good Luck!